# how to format html hanging indent under second word of first line

Tags: html, css

I want to place a hanging indent that is 2em greater than the width of the first word on a line. Example in monospaced font in a code section, but the need for variable width font in a div.

```
abcdef I want the hanging indent to be the width of abcdef plus 2em.
          It should look somewhat like this, but with variable width
          font.
```

Each word and each space character is already in a separate span tag if that helps. As in

```
<span>abcdef</span><span> </span><span>I</span>...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You can do this with CSS tables together with a negative `text-indent`

There is no need to wrap each word in a separate span.

Just wrap the first word in a span and the rest of the text in another span.

On the container element we set: `display: table`

On the two child spans we set: `display: table-cell`

Now we have 2 columns.

For the second column: we need to indent all the text starting from the second line and down.

We can do this by setting `padding-left` on the whole column, and then moving the first line back to its initial spot with a negative `text-indent`.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/py07v8tn/3/) (Resize to see the effect)

```css
p {
  display: table;
}
span {
  display: table-cell;
  background: #ccc;
  color: red;
}
span + span {
  color: black;
  text-indent: -1.8em;
  padding-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<p><span>abcdef</span>  <span>I want the hanging indent to be the width of abcdef plus 2em.It should look somewhat like this, but with variable width font.<span></p>
<hr />  
<p><span>abcdefghijklmnop</span>  <span>I want the hanging indent to be the width of abcdef plus 2em.It should look somewhat like this, but with variable width font.<span></p>
 <hr />    
<p><span>a</span>  <span>I want the hanging indent to be the width of abcdef plus 2em.It should look somewhat like this, but with variable width font.<span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had experimented a little with display: table-cell, but not enough, I guess. And while you say there is no need for all the spans... you are probably right, regarding this issue, but they are there for other reasons, so I thought I'd mention them. Because of the other reasons, I probably need to make your solution an extra layer (nesting level) of markup, that wraps the existing spans.... although I may not need the extra layer for the first word.

Comment: Turns out I didn't really need to set the container to display: table; as long as the adjacent spans were both display: table-cell   ! But the solution is working in context now, and this was the last of 4 alternate display modes to be created by applying different CSS to the same HTML, although I had to tweak one of the others after grouping the items in the second span.