# how to make all lines of text of <li> element have same indent when there is a padding

Tags: html, css, html-lists, padding

I have the following html/css code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
      li {
         display: block;
         background-color: green
      }

      a {
         padding-left: 40px;
      }

      li:hover{
         background-color: blue
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div style="width: 100px">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="/one">Apple 2 Thisisareallylongstringwithoutspaces</a></li>
         <li><a href="/one">Tea</a></li>
         <li><a href="/one">Milk</a></li>

         <div>
            <li><a href="/one">Kevin went to the jungle to explore and meets animals.</a></li>
            <li><a href="/one">David went overseas to work and earn money at a big company.</a></li>
            <li><a href="/one">James slept at home because he was too lazy to get up.</a></li> 
         </div>
      </ul> 
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have used `padding-left` in the hopes of achieving some indent, but whenever the text goes to a new line, this text on the new line is not indented in the same way that the first line of text is. Would anyone know how to make it so all lines receive the same padding/indent even when the text overflows to a new line? e.g. my desired result will see that the words "went","the","jungle","explore","meets" and "animals" will all have the same indent as "Kevin" in the 4th `<li>` element.

EDIT: As a follow up, how would one go about making the lines following the first line be more indented to the right by a certain amount? So in the aforementioned example, "went","the","jungle","explore","meets" and "animals" would be indented further to the right than "Kevin"

Comment: So then just add the padding to the `li` element instead of the `a` element in your CSS :)

Comment: what if I want to make the lines following the first line be slightly more indented to the right by a certain amount?

Comment: You mean a [hanging indent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021967/how-to-format-html-hanging-indent-under-second-word-of-first-line)? Also FYI, it is against SO guidelines to add more questions to your post. (Although in this case there's no point posting a new question because it is already answered on SO and would be closed as a duplicate.)

Comment: for the most part yes, though if possible I would also like to indent the first line (and the following lines even more) - from what I understand hanging indents are when the first line is not indented at all

Comment: Only if you write the CSS so that the first line has no indent :)

Comment: thank you - I'll keep the SO guidelines in mind